# How to disable all network adapters forever?

Tags: 16.04, networking, security

For security reasons I need to disable all network adapters in a way that you can't accidentally go online again (i.e. clicking on "Enable Networking", etc.). My device has to be an 100% offline device. No Bluetooth, no LAN, no Wi-FI - nothing.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: For any onboard NICs the BIOS usually has an option to disable them.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of the BIOS. Thank you!

Comment: You can also blacklist the drivers.

Comment: How does this work @chili555?

Comment: Please let us see the result of the terminal commands: `sudo lshw -C network` and also: `lsusb` As the result may be lengthy, post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Based on the result, I will propose a solution. In short, if the device driver is blacklisted, it cannot load and the device will never start.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26146610/